# Cannot add a column after deleting another column in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I cannot imagine there is such issue in BigQuery:

le's say if I drop a column using below command in BQ console for User table:
`Alter table User drop column name` -> successful

I am aware this column is preserved for 7 day(for time travel duration purpose).

But I cannot add any column anymore by running below command in BQ console:
`ALTER TABLE User add column first_name STRING`

Cause it will give an error like below even though the two columns have totally different naming:
`Column name was recently deleted in the table User. Deleted column name is reserved for up to the time travel duration, use a different column name instead.`

The above error is same as when I try to drop the same column again even with IF EXISTS:
`Alter table User drop IF EXISTS column name`

My question:

- Why is this issue will happen? After 7 days, Can I add new columns as usual?

Comment: Plus Running DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS also gives me exactly error which let me doubt what is the point of 'IF EXISTS' lol :

ALTER TABLE User DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the solution using UI suggested @Scott B, we can also do it using bq command:

Basically `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'ALTER TABLE User add column first_name STRING'` will fail to add a column. But I found a workaround
I can run bq update command instead like below:

1. bq show --schema --format=prettyjson DATASET.User > user_schema.json
2. Add a new column I want into file  user_schema.json
3. bp update DATASET.User user_schema.json

So this basically means it is a 100% bug in BigQuery SQL command

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your issue wherein I dropped a column named `employee_like_2` and then tried to add a new column named `new_column`.

[image]

There is already a created [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/242214893) for this issue. You may click on **+1** to bring more attention on the issue and **STAR** the issue so that you can be notified for updates.

For the meantime, a possible workaround is to manually add columns through **BigQuery UI**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: But we want to maintain schema in code rather than UI but I found something new